# Center Navigation Bar with FIXED WIDTH

Tags: html, css, navigation, centering

Someone told me that it would be hard to center an navigation bar with fixed width. Is it true? That's my itch right now.

Here's my navigation bar CSS:

```
nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 15px 0px 32px 0px;   
}

nav ul ul{
  display: none;
}


nav ul li{
  display: inline;
  float: left;  
}

nav ul a{
  color:#666;
  background-color:#CCC;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;    
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;     
}

nav ul a: hover{
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #F60;   
}
```

Here is my HTML CODES:

```
<nav>

    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="products_and_services.html">PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">BROCHURES</a></li>
            <li><a href="">BUSINESS CARDS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MAGAZINES</a></li>
            <li><a href="">BOOKS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">WEB DESIGN</a></li>
        </ul>          
    <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="support.html">SUPPORT</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="about_us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Why is your first css property still open ? Also `display:inline` and `float:left` can't work together. `float:left` automatically adds a `display:block` to your element

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  You have a `ul` child of another `ul` element.  The only valid children of a `ul` are `li`.  You need to wrap your child `ul` in an `li`

Comment: Nice Help Rippo. I'm taking note of that.

Comment: To Joseph, actually the <ul> after <li> are submenus of the parent <li>.

Answer (score 1):

First off, as a few other posters have pointed out, there are few issues with your HTML. If you're nesting `<ul></ul>` inside of another `<ul></ul>`, it has to be encapsulated in an `<li></li>`

Here is your HTML, corrected:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="products_and_services.html">PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">BROCHURES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">BUSINESS CARDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MAGAZINES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">BOOKS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">WEB DESIGN</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href="support.html">SUPPORT</a></li>
<li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
<li><a href="about_us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

To center this navigation you simply need to add this to your CSS:

```
nav { 
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note that the width can be whatever you want, but it's important to keep the margin:0 auto.

The CSS shorthand `margin: 0 auto;` evaluates to:

```
margin-top:0;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:auto;
```

[Here's jsfiddle to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/mJeST/)

Answer (score 0):

Centering a nav bar shouldn't be that tricky. Just as a very quick example I've written the below and it works fine:

Html:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test 2</li>
<li>Test 3</li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {position:relative; top:50px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:1024px; height:50px; background-color:#cdcdcd;}

nav ul {display:block; list-style-type:none; text-align:center;}

nav ul li {display:inline-block; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px;}
```

nav styles the overall nav bar, gives it a fixed width and height and then centers it using margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; then nav ul display:block sets the ul to be full width of the nav bar and text-align:center; makes sure the text is set to center. the nav ul li styles the individual list elements and display:inline-block; allows them to line up next to each other.

hope this helps

Comment: Glad it helped :) if it does the job would you be kind enough to mark it as the accepted answer please? Thanks

Comment: Yeah sure! But my reputation won't allow me to do it yet. :-(